# Catching a click event on a SELECT in IE prevents from selection

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I want to enlight a *select* and its *td* container when I click on like this:

```
$("#fordelegation").on("click", "td", function (evt) {
    $(".ui-state-focus").removeClass("ui-state-focus");
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-focus");
    $(evt.target).addClass("ui-state-focus");
});
```

You can test it on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sinsedrix/9Sudt/

With IE, I get a strange behaviour, I cannot select an option anymore.
Some people say they do not get this trick so here are the behaviour videos:

- good on FF: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B503hUUz979cMGI2NTRjYTEtNTY0OS00MTVhLWE5MzktNTY0Yjk1MmNiZGE3
- bad on IE: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B503hUUz979cZWNjOWY2YTQtZDBjZC00MGQyLWI2MDgtYzg1N2Q1ZWI0N2Uy

The question is : Where should I dig to fix the bad behaviour ?

I really get stuck on this trick :( so every  idea is welcome.

Comment: The dropdown has an empty default value in the video but not in the jsfiddle. Is that default value missing in the code or added by the browser? Also, what version of IE are you using?

Comment: The fiddle worked fine for me in IE8. Is your real code doing anything else? Just as an aside, note that setting the selection on click isn't enough since users might use the keyboard to tab between fields...

Comment: I use IE 8. The fiddle is a simplified version of my code. I also catch keyboard tabs but the problem appears just on click. No difference with a default selected value (see updated fiddle).

Answer (score 1):

edit 1
Setting the style directly works though
http://jsfiddle.net/9Sudt/37/

---

It all boils down to a IE bug, if you change the class of the select it is redrawn and closed.

See this stackoverflow question and the accepted answer
[JQuery select box focus problem in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202554/jquery-select-box-focus-problem-in-internet-explorer)

See this example in IE
http://jsfiddle.net/9Sudt/34/
If you click on the select a second time, it works again, because the class is not changed then

Comment: Thanks, I think I've fixed it. First I use "focusin" instead of "click". Then I wrote `$(".ui-state-focus").not($element).removeClass("ui-state-focus");` to avoid changing the current element state.